# Oracle: if TABLE_A exists, return count(*), else return 0;

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use only one SQL statement, I have tried following one but failed:

```
SELECT decode(TABLE_COUNT, 0, 0, SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A) FROM
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS TABLE_COUNT FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A'
)
```

Comment: My final purpose is get count from TABLE_A.  Since TABLE_A may not exists, I need check whether TABLE_A is exists first.   If TABLE_A exists, get count from it, otherwise regards the count is 0.

Comment: You can't. This is a very strong statement, that I just made: there is NO single SQL statement that can do what you want. The query is parsed before it is executed. True, in `decode` (or in `case` expression), the "...then" part is not evaluated (calculated) unless the "...when" part is TRUE. But this doesn't mean the parser will not parse the entire query, and throw an error if the name of an non-existent table is encountered.

Comment: The real question is, why do you want to do this "in a single SQL statement"? You can do it very easily in a short, simple PL/SQL block (either an anonymous one or a named one, a.k.a. a stored procedure).

Comment: If you have Oracle 12.1C the function `DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml` might be a option to use "The DBMS_XMLGEN package converts the results of a SQL query to a canonical XML format. The package takes an arbitrary SQL query as input, converts it to XML format, and returns the result as a CLOB"  ( https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xmlgen.htm#ARPLS69856  )

Comment: Thank Raymond Nijland, your solution is worth learning.   Thank mathguy , I think you are right,  I will split it to two simple SQL. For a product, simplicity is justice! :)

Answer (score 1):

An example of the `dbms_xmlgen` approach that @RaymondNijland referred to in a comment:

```
create table table_a (id) as select level from dual connect by level <= 10;

select nvl(max(to_number(
  xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) as c from ' || table_name))
    returning content)
  )), 0) as count
from user_tables
where table_name = 'TABLE_A';

     COUNT
----------
        10

drop table table_a purge;

select nvl(max(to_number(
  xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) as c from ' || table_name))
    returning content)
  )), 0) as count
from user_tables
where table_name = 'TABLE_A';

     COUNT
----------
         0
```

You can easily extend this to query multiple tables at once, or all tables in a schema, etc., by changing the filter and adding a group-by clause.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause may be of use in this case if the feature is available in the version of Oracle you are using. The following is what the code would look like.

NOTE: This is a SELECT statement even though it looks like PL/SQL code. The WITH clause supports the use of a PL/SQL declaration within it.

```
WITH
FUNCTION getCount(p_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS
v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||p_table_name INTO v_count;
  RETURN mycount;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
SELECT getCount('hr.employee') FROM DUAL;
```

The WHEN OTHERS traps the error when the table does not exist and returns 0. If the table exists, it returns the count from the table.

Hope this works for you.